# C++ Server OpenCV not working properly

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing, serversocket

I am working on android application which takes an image and then sends it to the server for processing. On Server I receive the image but unable to process it.
On android I capture the image:

```
cameraPreview.getCamera().takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback()
```

On Server side receive message is implemented as:

```
static int receiveMessage(int socket, char* buffer, int image_size) {
int num_bytes_read = 0;
while (num_bytes_read < image_size) {
    int read = recv(socket, 
    buffer + num_bytes_read, image_size - num_bytes_read, 0);
    if (read == -1) {
        std::cout << "Error: Connection error during image receive." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

After receiving the image only `std::cout` & `cv::imwrite` command works properly. After this whenever it come to the image processing my program simply hangs there (it's still running). No Exception or error can be shown.
Additionally: The Received Images can be processed properly by processing them separately in different program

**PS: I am working with opencv-3.0**

Comment: are you getting a correct image? when you call imwrite does it contain all data? However, I think it is problem about type.. could you please do this for me: std::cout << youtimage.channels(); << std::endl << yourimage.type();

Comment: Yes I am getting the correct image.... the same image work perfectly fine when I put it into the simple algorithm.... but hangs when I use it within server... even it hangs with imshow.... ( image.channels=3) & (image.type=16)

Comment: everything seems fine.. it is very strange that cv::imwrite works while cv::imshow not!

Comment: The program simply holds there while executing the command and never gets out of it....... whatever the process is except std::cout and cv::imwrite